# What I should use font icons or sprite images?

Tags: html, image, css, fonts

What I should use font icons or sprite images for better performance? What will 
be load faster and light weighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use font icons or sprite images when you have a lot of small separate images, you basically bundle them into one image so one request is done to get all the images.

Typically those are used for small icons for buttons, or icons in the navbar, and similar stuff. For example StackOverflow's editor buttons on the top (the bold, italic, etc.) probably use font images for that:

[image: SO editor buttons]

Imagine the case where you have had to load something like 10 different images just for that bar of buttons, that would be very inefficient.

Another example is emojies. There are thousands of emojies out there, imagine if you have to load each one of them in a separate request.

Currently with the modern websites, usually font icons are used much more than sprite images.

This also reduces the server load as well. It's all for efficiency purposes, and because we use small images to represent buttons instead of text sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment, this is really helpful. But sadly to say that, right now I am not able to vote up your comment as I have not that much reputation that is required.

Comment: @AnupMishra It is okay :)

Comment: Good job. A lot of detail + a good explanation! I'll upvote ya for that.

Answer (score 2):

there are two crucial points where I feel icon fonts can have an advantage:

- Overall file size
- Internet Explorer support

When you have a set of icons that you’d like to use on a given project, the larger the set of icons, the more likely an icon font will have a smaller overall file footprint.

Talking about performances, during a recent test I made on a set of about 30 icons, the icon fonts can reach a boost of about 240% compared to sprite images.
Also, icon fonts work as far back as IE6.

On the other hand, vector icons are resizable up and down without losing quality, extra sharp on retina displays. It can also support multi-color icons.

I recommend [this](https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/) post for any further reference.

Hope this could help,
L.

Comment: Sprite images are not explicitly vector. From where did you get that `240%` percentage

Comment: That's true, sprites are not explicitly vectored. 
On one recent project, I generated an icon font of 29 icons with IcoMoon tool. That very tool allows exporting the same set as an SVG sprite.
The icon font was 7kb
The SVG sprite was 17kb
That's an increase of performance about 240%

Comment: Yeah but basically you can get much lower or much higher gains depending on many factors, perhaps you should state that you got `240%` in filesize improvement **on your test**. Many people could start taking that as a general measure. Also I didn't know older IE didn't support sprite images, today I learned.